# Groovy SQL Connections not being closed

Tags: sql, groovy, connection, datasource

I am running some unit-tests, but I am seeing some strange behaviour with regards connections not being released to the pool after use (which inevitably results in the unit tests hanging when the number of tests reach the pool size)

To demonstrate, I have created a really simple unit-test:

```
@Before void setUp(){
    sql = new Sql(getDataSource())
    println getDataSource().getNumActive()
}

@After void tearDown(){
    sql.close()
}

@Test void test1(){
    println sql.rows("select 1")
}
@Test void test2(){
    println sql.rows("select 1")
}
@Test void test3(){
    println sql.rows("select 1")
}
@Test void test4(){
    println sql.rows("select 1")
}
```

In my setup method, my getDataSource() method just returns a static, initialised BasicDataSource (so this is the same datasource every time).

I am also explicitly calling close on my Sql object in the teardown method, even though Groovy says in its [docs](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#Sql%28javax.sql.DataSource%29) that you dont have to when constructing your Sql object with a DataSource

```
public Sql(javax.sql.DataSource dataSource)
Constructs an SQL instance using the given DataSource. Each operation will use a Connection from the DataSource pool and close it when the operation is completed putting it back into the pool.
```

However, when I run the tests the number of active connections continues to increase, and if i set the max pool size to be 2, then it will hang after the second test indefinitely.

Can anyone advise why the connections are not being returned?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was a stupid problem..

I hadn't noticed that the testclass was extending another class that had duplicate @Before setup method in it, so was obviously doing funny things with the pool. Removing that has solved the problem.